# php redirect the user in web page expire

Tags: php

how to redirect the user in web page expire to different page.

i have my php code when user click back button from page4.php to page3.php it give him web page expire. i would like to direct him to different page instead.

my code

Test2.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="test3.php" method="post">
Username: <br><input type="text" name="username"></br>

<input type="submit" name = 'submit1' value= 'Login'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Test3.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['username']= $_POST['username'];

echo "<br> Hi $username.</br>";

?>

<form action="test4.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name = 'submit' value= 'click me'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Test4.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "<br> Hi $username.</br>";

?>
```

Comment: `if { condition - do something } else { do something else }`

Comment: it's because you posted your form. you should redirect after posting a form.

Comment: @Mortezalpo i didnt get you, can you please write it in my code. and give me example. please thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code to something like this:

Test2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['redirect']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['redirect']);
    header('Location: logout.php'); 
}
if($_POST && isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $_SESSION['username']= $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['redirect']=True;
    header('Location: Test3.php');
}
?>
<html>
<body>

<form action="Test2.php" method="post">
Username: <br><input type="text" name="username"></br>

<input type="submit" name = 'submit1' value= 'Login'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Test3.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header('Location: Test2.php');
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if($_POST)
{
    ...your actions
    header('Location: Test4.php');
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php

echo "<br> Hi $username.</br>";

?>

<form action="Test3.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name = 'submit' value= 'click me'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your code. when click back button i want to be redirect to "header("Location:logout.php");" where do i change this instead of web page expire ?

Comment: @Hadi I've added that action in `Test2.php` code. check it.

Comment: @Mortezalpo no it doesn't work. when i open the browser at `test2.php` it take me direct to `logout.php` not allowing me to enter the name. can you fix it please.

Comment: @Hadi yes, Sorry I got wrong. I've updated code. check it again.

Comment: @Mortezalpo it open once, when trying for the second time it just open `logout.php` and hang there..

Comment: @Hadi it's because in `logout.php` you should remove that session. I've added that action in `Test2.php` code. check it.